# scrape image URL from online clothing site using R or data miner tool

Tags: r, rvest

I want to scrape image URLs from 'https://www.raworange.com/collections/all-clothing' site. There are total 9 pages so want to scrape images from all pages and also want to download that url with image name. I tried this code:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.raworange.com/collections/all-clothing"
imgsrc <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_node(xpath = '#bc-sf-filter-products img') %>%
  html_attr('src')
imgsrc
download.file(paste0(url, imgsrc), destfile = basename(imgsrc))
```

This does not work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, you mean you aren't getting any matches? Can you edit into your question an example of an HTML element that you're trying to match but failing to?

Comment: I am new for web scraping so i don't know how to match the element. I want the url of all the images.

Comment: Which is why I asked you for an example of the element you're trying to match so that we could help you match it. OK, well at first glance that's a CSS selector not an XPath selector, so try using `html_node(css = '')` instead (and I guess you'll want html_nodes plural eventually too).

Comment: It works, but how to do page navigation and the name of image?

Comment: Page navigation: you can either construct the URLs yourself, the pattern is quite simple, or look for e.g. '#bc-sf-filter-bottom-pagination a' and remember the page URLs you've processed so far and process any new ones (you may have to filter out the link back to the first page to avoiding duplicating it). The name: what exactly do you want to use as the name? You could go up two elements from the image take to the `a` that links to the product page and take the end of the URL from that? Although you've got two images per product, so you'll need to differentiate somehow. Up to you!

Comment: As a image name i want the same name which is written below the image on the site.for ex. on the website the name of 1st image is 'Nothing To Wear Crop Top', So i want that name with url.

Comment: OK, that's easy enough: from an image tag navigate up to its parent that matches div.product_preview and in that find h2.product_title.

Comment: I did not get your point.

Comment: And did you run the above code? because when I run the code some of the image url are repeated.

Comment: No, I don't have time to do that. I don't even really know the library you're trying to use. I'm just trying to help steer you in the right direction. If you're getting duplicates you'll either have to figure out where these come from and modify your search to filter out the duplicates, or record all of the URLs you have seen so far and only process new ones.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. Can you please clear out that how to set the name. Thanks for help.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can't navigate back up the tree in rvest. I'd guess you'll have to look for `html_nodes(css='div.product-preview')` instead, and then for each of those pipe that into `html_nodes(css='h2.product_title') html_text()` to get the title, and `html_node(css='img')` to get the image URLs as you're doing now. I do have R installed somewhere so may have time to try this later but I can't right now.

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments this will read the page and build a list of pairs of the product name, from the h2 under each item and a list of img URLs from the product preview:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

url <- "https://www.raworange.com/collections/all-clothing"
html <- read_html(url)
products <- html %>% html_nodes(css='div.product-preview')

products %>% map(function(product) {
  name <- product %>% html_nodes(css='h2.product_title') %>% html_text()
  imgs <- product %>% html_nodes(css='img') %>% html_attr('src')
  c(name, list(imgs))
})
```

I also suggested you get URLs for the other pages from ul#bc-sf-filter-bottom-pagination but it looks like this is populated at load time by script, so can't easily be scraped by rvest. I think you'll have to look at the paging URLs ina browser and construct them yourself for your code to loop through.

Comment: Thanks Rup. I'll try to write the text or csv file of the final result, whicg get after performing the function. But it displays NULL as a result.